# What do we call a stronger form of word aside from synonym?

Tags: synonyms

For example, *see - stare - glare* or *hit - strike - smack*.

They are synonyms but  deliver more power in their meaning/sound and sometimes have more exclusive usage, yet deliver the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first word that came to my mind was "Superlative"

As per dictionary.com, the definition of "superlative" is the following

The form of an adjective indicating the greatest degree of the quality that the adjective describes.

Examples: 
Best is the superlative form of good; fastest is the superlative form of fast; most charming is the superlative form of charming.

But the word "superlative may fall short of your expectations, since you are looking for a word that indicates a stronger form of a word that is "relatively" stronger than the previous one (and NOT only the one that indicates the greatest degree)